# Pandas Datetime format conversion error yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-mm or yyyy/mm as a string

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a bunch of data in the form of yyyy-mm-dd and I need it in the form of yyyy-mm (string format) so I can plot monthly bar charts

I don't receive any errors but it outputs incorrect data for some values and correct values for other

```
df = dx

print(df["Collection_End_Date"])


df['Date_Modified'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Collection_End_Date']).dt.strftime('%m/%y')

print(df["Date_Modified"])

0       25/02/2019
1       06/01/2019
2       10/02/2019
3       17/01/2019
4       18/03/2019
           ...    
1149    27/01/2019
1150    04/03/2019
1151    10/02/2019
1152    10/03/2019
1153    24/02/2019
Name: Collection_End_Date, Length: 1154, dtype: object
0       02/19
1       06/19
2       10/19
3       01/19
4       03/19
        ...  
1149    01/19
1150    04/19
1151    10/19
1152    10/19
1153    02/19
Name: Date_Modified, Length: 1154, dtype: object
```

The data in the csv file is yyyy-mm-dd but it outputs in the form of dd/mm/yyyy. After modifying the data it outputs data sometimes as mm/yyyy or as dd/yyyy. I need the data in a string format ideally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [pd.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and `to_period` and `strftime` to change the format of date

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Collection_End_Date": ["2019-01-07 12:00:00", "2019-01-07 12:00:00", "2019-02-08 12:00:00", "2019-01-05 12:00:00", "2019-01-05 12:00:00"]
    }
)

df['Collection_End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Collection_End_Date'])
df['month_year'] = df['Collection_End_Date'].dt.to_period('M')
```

```
    Collection_End_Date month_year
0   2019-01-07 12:00:00   2019-01
1   2019-01-07 12:00:00   2019-01
2   2019-02-08 12:00:00   2019-02
3   2019-01-05 12:00:00   2019-01
4   2019-01-05 12:00:00   2019-01
```

## if you want to replace - with / in date you can do

```
df["Collection_End_Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Collection_End_Date"])
df['month_year'] = df['Collection_End_Date'].dt.to_period('M')
df['month_year'] = df['month_year'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m')
```

```
    Collection_End_Date  month_year
0   2019-01-07 12:00:00    2019/01
1   2019-01-07 12:00:00    2019/01
2   2019-02-08 12:00:00    2019/02
3   2019-01-05 12:00:00    2019/01
4   2019-01-05 12:00:00    2019/01
```

Comment: hi thxs for your answer, its giving me the exact same output for both programs you have suggested. It seems to always take the dd date if its less than 12 so it might be an American time interpretation

Comment: @ritzrori second answer just change the format 2019-01 to 2019/01

Comment: I have taken random date in the dataframe try the solution in your own dataframe and check if the solution is solving your problem or not

Comment: Hi do you mean I should manually change it from the Dataframe so yyyy-mm to yyyy/mm etc because I cannot do that as the logs come in that format (yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: if you want yyyy/mm `df['month_year'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m')` this line actually converts this

Comment: you want the format in yyyy/mm  or mm/yyyy or yyyy-mm or mm-yyyy?